# Auto generating report after load test has completed TFS2010, TFS2012

Tags: testing, tfs, visual-studio-2012, load-testing

Is there a build-in possibility in Visual Studio 2012 to setup a scheduled Load test run and generate a report with comparing current test run with the previous test run?

Comment: What will be the format of the report? Do you mean like an excel comparison report?

Comment: I would go for a PDF file, which would be saved somewhere on a network drive. But if there is a possibility to auto-generate excel report, then it would also be okay. Thanks

Comment: I don't think this can be done, unless you write your own tool for doing that. However, if the 'Auto generating' is not so strict requirement, you can create excel reports manually. [How to: Create Load Test Performance Reports Using Microsoft Excel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997707.aspx)